# Display order in CollectionView in Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I want to display my collectionview in the below format:

```
Item0 Item3
Item1 Item4
Item2 Item5
```

But by default coillectionView displays in the below format:

```
Item0 Item1
Item2 Item3
Item4 Item5

                                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2" />
                            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
```

Using the above code to display items in 2 columns

Comment: Create a custom order in your Collection, you cannot change the view if that's what you are looking for!

Comment: Why not set the Orientation to ```Horizontal``` and set the right span for the row number?

Comment: You may refer to this official doc: [Horizontal grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#horizontal-grid).